# Get arguments passed to main module(VC++ exe) inside sub module (C#.NET dll )

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, command-line-arguments

What are the ways to get start arguments(command line arguments) passed to exe(built from VC++ code) inside the loaded dll(C#.net code)
I tried to use Process.Startinfo.Arguments from dll, but it is not returning anything.

Comment: Post your code that you're using to run the EXE.

Comment: I would assume that exe is written on C++ and it is using managed dll written on C#. So, why can't you provide an interface inside dll to pass command line arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() to retrieve the original command line arguments.